# How to show few lines with jstl into html td tag?

Tags: jstl

All,

I have simple print in my website, using JSTL into a td html tag, very simple print, but I would like to show just few lines, maybe the last 5, is there a way to do this?

See below:

```
<td class="domain"><c:out value="${row.domain}" escapeXml="false" /></td>
```

Comment: Few lines of what? Last 5 what? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: The row.domain is a var that contain a text with few lines, for example: 10 and I would like to show just the latest 5 for example.